# Is this correct non-trivial program that print itself as output? Print the following twice, the second time in quotes

Tags: computation

This was give by Scoot Aaronsson in his lectures.
Print the following, the second time in quotes . (The program)
"Print the following, the second time in quotes" (The output)

I don't get this. What I understand is this : 
Print the following, the second time in quotes.
", the second time in quotes"

This may be a silly question but can anyone just explain how am I wrong or right ?